# Intersection of two polynomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

In the $4$-dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}^4$ with coordinates $x,y,z,t$, consider $X$ as the union of the planes
$$
X'=\{x=y=0\}
$$
and
$$
X''=\{z=x-t=0\}
$$

(I'm working on a algebraically closed field; everything is friendly here).

I need to compute the ideal $I(X)$. I tried to compute generators for the ideal $I(X')\cap I(X'')$, but algebra is the topic in which I'm the worst. I tried to establish the generators that are in both ideals and eventually came to
$$
I(X)=\langle xz,yz,xy-ty,x^2-tx\rangle
$$
where $\langle f\rangle$ denotes the ideal generated by $f$ in $\mathbb{k}[x,y,z,t]$.

I'm not sure if this is correct and could use some help figuring this out.

Comment: Your claim is that $I(X) = I(X')I(X'')$.  This is not true in general (take $X''=X'$ for example), but it is immediate that $I(X) = \sqrt{I(X')I(X'')}$.  So one way of saying it is that you need to somehow verify that $I(X')I(X'')$ is a radical ideal.

Comment: I'll try it and see what I get from it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you want to prove the following: $$(X,Y)\cap(X-T,Z)=(XZ,YZ,X(X-T),Y(X-T)).$$

Let $f\in(X,Y)\cap(X-T,Z)$. Write $$f=Xf_1+Yf_2=(X-T)g_1+Zg_2\qquad(*)$$ Now sending $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ to $0$ obtain $g_1(0,0,0,T)=0$, so $g_1=Xh_1+Yh_2+Zh_3$. Plugging this in $(*)$ we get $$f=Xf_1+Yf_2=X(X-T)h_1+Y(X-T)h_2+Zk\qquad(**)$$ Sending $X$ and $Y$ to $0$ obtain $k(0,0,Z,T)=0$, so $k=Xk_1+Yk_2$ and you are done.

Comment: If you want to see how to use Gröbner bases for finding the intersection of two ideals (in a polynomial ring over a field) take a look at [this example](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/compute-the-intersection-of-two-polynomial-ideals/).

Comment: So, basically, you showed me a way to proof that my first calculation was correct?
I'm also assuming that $k=h_3+g_2$ in your calculations.